# Double free coruption

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

I have a class call grid. The class holds two 2d char arrays for storing a grid...
The class has two functions for creating the memory for the grid and releasing the memory for the grid.

Grid.h

```
private:
char **gridOne;
char **gridTwo;
```

Grid.cpp

```
void Grid::allocateGridMem()
{
   _gridOne = new char*[gridRowCount()];
   _gridTwo = new char*[gridRowCount()];

   for(int i =0; i < gridColumnCount(); ++i){
      *(_gridOne + i) = new char[gridColumnCount()];
      *(_gridTwo + i) = new char[gridColumnCount()];
   }
}

void Grid::dealocateGridMem()
{
   if(_gridOne != 0)
   {
      for(int i =0; i < gridRowCount(); ++i){
         delete [] *(_gridOne + i);
      }
      delete [] _gridOne;
      _gridOne = 0;
   }

   if(_gridTwo != 0)
   {
      for(int i =0; i < gridRowCount(); i++){
         delete [] *(_gridTwo + i);
      }
      delete [] _gridTwo;
      _gridTwo = 0;
   }
}
```

The problem is happening in the deallocation of the memory which I receive the following error.

```
    *** glibc detected *** ./a.out: double free or corruption (out): 0x088c9318 ***
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6b591)[0xb756c591]
    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6cde8)[0xb756dde8]
    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb7570ecd]
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x21)[0xb775c741]
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdaPv+0x1d)[0xb775c79d]
    ./a.out[0x804a7b9]
    ./a.out[0x8049cb6]
    ./a.out[0x804b8f3]
    ./a.out[0x804c06a]
    ./a.out[0x804b71d]
    ./a.out[0x80498eb]
    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0xb7517bd6]
    ./a.out[0x8049521]
    ======= Memory map: ========
    08048000-0804f000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 920728     /home/a.out
    0804f000-08050000 r--p 00006000 08:02 920728     /home/a.out
    08050000-08051000 rw-p 00007000 08:02 920728     /home/a.out
    088c7000-088e8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
    b7300000-b7321000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    b7321000-b7400000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    b7500000-b7501000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    b7501000-b7654000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 19796293   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
    b7654000-b7655000 ---p 00153000 08:02 19796293   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
    b7655000-b7657000 r--p 00153000 08:02 19796293   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
    b7657000-b7658000 rw-p 00155000 08:02 19796293   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
    b7658000-b765b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    b765b000-b7678000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 19791955   /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
    b7678000-b7679000 r--p 0001c000 08:02 19791955   /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
    b7679000-b767a000 rw-p 0001d000 08:02 19791955   /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
    b767a000-b767b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    b767b000-b769f000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 19796301   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm-2.11.1.so
    b769f000-b76a0000 r--p 00023000 08:02 19796301   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm-2.11.1.so
    b76a0000-b76a1000 rw-p 00024000 08:02 19796301   /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm-2.11.1.so
    b76a1000-b778a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 28708531   /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
    b778a000-b778b000 ---p 000e9000 08:02 28708531   /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
    b778b000-b778f000 r--p 000e9000 08:02 28708531   /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
    b778f000-b7790000 rw-p 000ed000 08:02 28708531   /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
    b7790000-b7797000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    b77a5000-b77a8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    b77a8000-b77a9000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
    b77a9000-b77c4000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 19791897   /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
    b77c4000-b77c5000 r--p 0001a000 08:02 19791897   /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
    b77c5000-b77c6000 rw-p 0001b000 08:02 19791897   /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
    bf83a000

-bf84f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

I have checked all my pointers that they are not being changed to something else in execution and that every check and balance one can think of is happening rite. I have been pulling my hair out for the last few hours and still nothing.

I am running this with gcc on ubuntu 10 system.

Should also note that I have changed names etc for the purpose of this post and have only included the code I though to be of value.

EDIT:

Fixed the syntax problem however the original code has this I just typed it out to quickly and did not proof read.

Any help is greatly appreciated and worth a gold star in my book.
I am very much an advanced users of gdb and have used this with this issue but my thinking that it is a problem maybe in external library. I can not see any issues with the memory and how it is scoped just hoping someone has seen something like this. For all purposes this code is fine.

Comment: Do you get a line number and what would be the equivalent line in your code?

Comment: I suggest you to learn about valgrind and gdb.

Comment: Are you somehow making a copy of this object, but don't have a copy-constructor that copies \_gridOne/\_gridTwo ?

Comment: Is your copy constructor and your assignment operator private, virtual and null?

Comment: Stop doing your own memory management. Use the tools provided for you in the STL. If you want to write C code then fine but in C++ we abstract away all that memory management stuff by using smart objects.

Comment: Anywhere you use `new T[N]` you should be using `std::vector<T>(N);`, no reason not to.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
for(int i =0; i < gridColumnCount(); ++i){
   _gridOne = new char[gridColumnCount()];
   _gridTwo = new char[gridColumnCount()];
}
```

to

```
for(int i =0; i < gridRowCount(); ++i){
   _gridOne[i] = new char[gridColumnCount()];
   _gridTwo[i] = new char[gridColumnCount()];
}
```

Besides, don't do

```
*(array + i)
```

but

```
array[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably it should be `_gridOne[i]` instead of `_gridOne` inside the loop of `allocateGridMem`. But please, avoid such low-level operations whenever possible and use a high-level component like `boost::numeric::ublas::matrix` instead.

Comment: Definitely should be `_gridOne[i]` and `_gridTwo[i]` in `allocateGridMem`, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Does that `Grid` class of yours have a ***copy constructor*** and an ***assignment operator***? Otherwise, if you copy such objects, this error would be what happens.

I suggest you ***stop doing manual resource management*** and make `Grid` a thin two-dimensional wrapper around a `std::vector<char>` which manages memory.

Comment: It seems someone went through and down-voted all the answers. I suppose there is no reason which that someone would care to publish?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install valgrind`, run `valgrind myprogram` and 99% of memory allocation bugs become obvious.

At least one of the problems is that you are assigning the row (should be `_gridOne[i]`) over the top of the array pointer.  Compile with `-Werror -Wall -W` and many errors like this will become obvious at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the STL and vectors:

```
class Grid
{
    std::vector<std::vector<char> >    grid1;
    std::vector<std::vector<char> >    grid2;

    public:
       Grid(int col,int row)
           : grid1(col, std::vector<char>(row))
           , grid2(col, std::vector<char>(row))
        {}
 };
```

All done.

If you want to get fancy look at boost Matrix.